# how to keep a radio button checked inside a dojo dgrid?

Tags: radio-button, dojo, checked, dgrid

how to keep a radio button checked inside a dojo dgrid ?

i m getting previously checked values from backend , able to display values , but radio button remains unchecked !!

any resources or solution ?

data-dojo-props="selectionMode:'single',noDataMessage:'No Data',pageSizeOptions    : [10, 15, 20, 25,50,100]" data-dojo-id = "id_4002_grid" >
    
     
       Select        
       Dealer #      
       Name          
       City          
       State/Province
       User Role

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that radio buttons by nature cannot have multiple selected at once within a group.  dgrid gives each radiobutton in the column the same name (based on the column's `field`), which registers them all as part of the same group, so that selecting a different one will naturally deselect the previous one.

If you need more than one item to be selectable at once, then perhaps you want a checkbox instead?